# Help needed with joomla template installation

Tags: joomla, template

I got a new template which is bit huge as compared to my connection speed (15mb). When I tried the normal way, couldnt use the upload and install it. Since its doing nothing (time out).

Is there any way that I could manually upload via FTP and install the template?

Comment: you certainly can. Which version of Joomla are you using? Also you can install via a external Url too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to [this page](http://docs.joomla.org/Installing_a_template):

> Templates can also be installed via FTP without packaging them. Simply
>   select the template folder on your PC and upload it to your server,
>   using your favorite FTP software. Be sure you upload the template
>   folder to the directory: /path_to_joomla/templates/ - where
>   /path_to_joomla/ is the location of your Joomla! installation on the
>   server. This method is mostly used when you have created a template
>   yourself, and do not want to have to package it to install the
>   template, or if you want to upload more than one template at once.